# python efficiency: counting key occurrences in dict

Tags: python

Trying to get the unique values of a `dict` key and the # of times they appear in the `list`. This works, but feels janky:

```
a = [ {'pid': 1 }, {'pid': 1}, {'pid': 1}, {'pid': 2}, {'pid': 2}, {'pid': 3} ]
b = { x['pid']: len([f for f in a if f['pid'] == x['pid']]) for x in a }
b
```

Yielding:

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(d['pid'] for d in a)
print(c)
# Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1})
```

Comment: short and sweet